# Hibernate cascading order for multiple fields - object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, cascade

I have following Entities

```
class A {
    @OneToMany(cascade = ALL)
    List<B> b;
    @OneToMany(cascade = ALL)
    List<C> c;
}

class B {
    @ManyToOne
    A a
}

class C {
    @ManyToOne
    A a;
    @ManyToOne
    B b;
}
```

Now when I execute following code in a transaction

```
A a = repository.findOne(id);
B b = new B();
C c = new C();
c.setB(b);
a.addB(b);
a.addC(c);
repository.save(a);
```

I get following exception from hibernate:

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

My code works if I save `a` after I have added `b`, because then `b` is saved before `c` is.

I'm guessing the order in which the persist is cascaded is important. Is there any way I can make sure b is cascaded before c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong but I don't think it is possible to make sure that your list of Bs are cascaded first, it wouldn't be the best practice anyways.

I think your simplest option is to add cascade persist to the relationship from C to B.

```
class C {
    @ManyToOne
    A a;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = PERSIST)
    B b;
}
```